# Keyboard shortcut to show/hide hidden files in Finder in macOS Mojave

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, mojave, macos

In macOS Sierra, it used to be <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. But that does not appear to work in macOS Mojave. Has something changed?

What is the keyboard shortcut to show/hide hidden files in Finder without restarting in macOS Mojave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that still works for me on 10.14.1 Mojave

Comment: I get Siri appearance

Comment: @Mowzer that might be because you've assigned that keyboard shortcut to activate Siri. Go to System Preferences > Siri and check what keyboard shortcut you've assigned there. If it's `shift + command + .`, change it.